# Is reaction between SiO2 and CaO is Lewis acid and base reaction?

Tags: acid-base

In my textbook it is written that the slag forming reaction between silicate and calcium oxide is acid base reaction.
But this reaction is not Arrhenius definition of acid base reaction because this happens without water.
Also this reaction is not Brønsted–Lowry definition of acid base reaction because there is no proton donating.
I only know one more definition of acid and base, that is Lewis definition.
So is it okay to consider this reaction as Lewis acid and base reaction?
If that is the case, is it okay to assume that $\ce{O^2-}$ is the electron pair donor and $\ce{Si}$ is electron pair accepter?

Comment: This is a general question, which could be rewritten in a more generalized way, like this : Any oxygenated salt can be theoretically formed by a reaction between a metallic oxide and a non-metal oxide. Examples : $\ce{ CaO + SO3 -> CaSO4}$, or $\ce{Al2O3 + 3 N2O5 -> 2 Al(NO3)3}$. So the question becomes : Is it OK to assume that $\ce{O^{2-}}$ is the electron pair donor and the non-metal ($\ce{S}$ or $\ce{N}$) is the electron pair acceptor ?

Comment: You are right. Thank you for your meta-cognitive advice.

Comment: It is an acid-base reaction in the Lux-Flood definition: Hereby the acid is the oxide anion acceptor, the base is the oxide anion donator.

Comment: Yeah, it's Lux-Flood https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid%E2%80%93base_reaction#Lux%E2%80%93Flood_definition